# Error in bubble sort program

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I'm getting an error trying to sort array elements using bubble sort algorithm.
The error happens after accepting array elements from user.

reference:
http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/bubble-sort/

code:

```
package com.interview.programs;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void bubble(int array[])
    {
        int n=array.length;
        int k;
        for(int m=n;m>=0;m--)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n-1;i--)
            {
                k=i+1;
                if(array[i] > array[k])
                {
                    swap(i, k, array);
                }
            }
            print(array);
        }
    }
    private static void swap(int i, int j, int[] array)
    {
        int temp;
        temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=temp;
    }
    private static void print(int[] array)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" "+array[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BubbleSort b=new BubbleSort();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.println("How many number you want to sort? ");
        n=input.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        b.bubble(array);
        System.out.println("Your sorted array numbers are: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(+array[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
How many number you want to sort? 
3
Enter numbers: 
6
3
9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.interview.programs.BubbleSort.bubble(BubbleSort.java:14)
    at com.interview.programs.BubbleSort.main(BubbleSort.java:50)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for(int i=0;i<n-1;i--)` have `i++` instead?

Comment: ohh ya... thanks lot.. solved problem...:)

Answer (score 1):

in method bubble
          `for(int i=0;i<n-1;i--)`

change i-- to i++

Answer (score 1):

`Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is raised when you try to access a negative index from an array or a index bigger than its length.

In this case, you tried to access the index -1 in your second *for* inside the bubble method - `for(int i=0;i<n-1;i--)`. Changing `i--` to `i++`will fix it as you're starting `i` from `0` and want it to increments until `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

change i-- to i++ in your for(int i=0; i < n-1;i--)

Answer (score 0):

An array index out of bounds exception is what happens when you try to access an item in the array that doesn't exist. In your case that is element -1. Arrays can only contain elements  with indexes greater than 0.

When you get errors like this, if you read the error it will give you info, and a line number. Also it's probably better to google for the specific error (e.g.: what is java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception) than to use stack overflow.